# How to show/hide buttons in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to show "Disapprove" button when button state is "approve" and "Approve" button to "pending" state. I have pass the values correctly but both buttons shows always.

**This is my .ts file**

```
    export class NotificationComponent implements OnInit {

      notices: notification[] = [];
      public approve_show: boolean = false;
      public disapprove_show: boolean = false;

      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private router: Router,
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {

    var url = "http://localhost:3000/notification/view";

    this.http.get<any>(url).subscribe(res => {
      this.notices = res;
      var i = 0;

      for (var prop in res) {
        if (res.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          // console.log(res[i].state)          
          if (res[i].state == 'Approved') {
            console.log("approved")
            this.disapprove_show = true
          }
          else {
            this.approve_show = true
          }
          i++;
        }
      }

    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
}
```

**This is my html code**

```
<button *ngIf="approve_show" mat-raised-button class="approve_btn">Approve</button>
<button *ngIf="disapprove_show"  mat-raised-button color="warn" style="width:100px;">Disapprove</button>
```

Comment: Debug your code. You loop multiple times and execute both parts of the if/else on different iterations of the loop. Use break points to see what actually happens.

Comment: You don't need 2 variables. You can use `!` in condition

Comment: what is the object returned from GET call?  For some of the properties of the response object the `approve_show` is set to true and for others `disapprove_show` is set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since your using this for a list use the following.
`<button *ngIf="res.state=='Approved'"  mat-raised-button color="warn" style="width:100px;">`

The issue is that your using a global variable for the buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Ehy, your code is fine. 
You should fix the problem adding this.approve_show = false after this.disapprove_show = true and this.disapprove_show = false after this.approve_show = true.

The problem was that both the variables were true at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (res[i].state == 'Approved') { 
console.log("approved") 
this.disapprove_show = true 
this.approve_show = false
} else {
this.approve_show = true 
this.disapprove_show = false
}
```

As per the requirement it seems like only one button will be visible at a time...

Please let me know if I am wrong here...

Comment: I have use this code also. But this is not working. Thank you anyway.